# Noobish JavaScript Nested If-Else Statement Help/Advice/Pointers/YouNameIt

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I just started learning JavaScript (Today actually) and I'd really appreciate some help with nested if-else statements. I thought I'd write a simple program to practice, and it seems that every if-else statement in my if blocks executes regardless of which parameter I put in. Any pointers or even things you notice that aren't germane to the problem at hand are appreciated. Thanks again. My code is below.

EDIT: I've gotten it now, and learned the error of my ways. Thanks to everyone who commented and gave advice so quickly.

```
var playerOne = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors'); 
var playerTwo = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors'); 

var fight = function (playerOne, playerTwo)
{ 
    if( playerOne == 'rock' || 'Rock')
    { 
        if (playerTwo == 'paper' || 'Paper')
        {
            alert('Player Two Wins!');
        }
        else if (playerTwo == 'rock' || 'Rock')
        {
            alert('Tie!');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Player One wins!');
        }
    }

        if(playerOne == 'paper' || 'Paper')
        { 
            if (playerTwo == 'paper' || 'Paper')
            {
                alert('Tie!');
            }
            else if (playerTwo == 'rock' || 'Rock')
            {
                alert('Player One Wins!'); 
            }
            else 
            {
                alert('Player Two  wins!');
            }
        }

        if (playerOne == 'scissors' || 'Scissors')
        {
             if (playerTwo == 'paper' || 'Paper')
             {
                alert('Player One Wins!');
             }
            else if (playerTwo == 'rock' || 'Rock')
            {
                alert('Player Two Wins!');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Tie!');
            }
        }

};

fight(playerOne, playerTwo);
```

Comment: You can't do code like this `playerOne == 'rock' || 'Rock'`. You'd need to do `playerOne == 'rock' || playerOne == 'Rock'`

Comment: You must compare for each alternate possibility: `if (playerOne == 'paper' || playerOne == 'Paper')` or simply: `if playerOne.toLowerCase() == 'paper'`

Comment: A switch statement could make this a bit cleaner...

Comment: @bpeterson76 also `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Oh alright, I've seen the .toLowerCase() method in java, I just didn't know if you could use it in JavaScript. I'll try that, thank you. Any reason the statements are all executing?

Comment: The result of the (misplaced) expression `'rock' || 'Rock'` is truthy so the `if` is satisfied

Comment: The reason that the JavaScript interpreter didn't fail on your syntax for those if statements (like it would, in say, C#), is because in JS strings can be used as truthy statements.  An empty string evaluates to false, all other strings (including whitespace only strings) evaluate to true.  e.g. `!!"paper"` vs `!!""`

Comment: the '==' sign is case insensitive as far as I know and is not necessary so the `playerOne == 'rock' || playerOne == 'Rock'` is simplified to: `playerOne == 'rock'` or == should be replaced by === as a strict case sensitive match. Hope I helped :)

Comment: this may do better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: playerOne == 'rock' || 'Rock'. You'd need to do playerOne == 'rock' || playerOne == 'Rock

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov the `==` operator is definitely *not* case-insensitive in javascript. (in fact i've never seen a language where it is.) the only difference between `==` and `===` is that the former does type conversion before comparison. `==` is the *equality* operator whereas `===` is the *identity* operator.

Answer (score 2):

As several people have pointed out, your `if` statements need to be in the form of:

```
if (playerOne == 'paper' || playerOne == 'Paper')
```

or the more succinct:

```
if (playerOne.toLowerCase() == 'paper')
```

The problem is that `playerOne == 'paper' || 'Paper'` will always return a "Truthy" value (see http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript for more detail on Truthy and Falsy values).

As an aside, while there's absolutely nothing wrong with multiple `if` statements, if I were coding this exercise my way would involve less `if` statements (and look a little like this:

```
var playerOne = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors');
var playerTwo = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors');
var fists = {
    "rock": {
        "beats": "scissors",
        "loses": "paper"
    },
    "paper": {
        "beats": "rock",
        "loses": "scissors"
    },
    "scissors": {
        "beats": "paper",
        "loses": "rock"
    }
}

var fight = function (playerOne, playerTwo) {
    playerOne = playerOne.toLowerCase();
    playerTwo = playerTwo.toLowerCase();

    if (fists[playerOne] === undefined || fists[playerTwo] === undefined) {
        alert('Someone threw an unknown fist!');
    } else if (fists[playerOne].beats === playerTwo) {
        alert('Player One wins!');
    } else if (fists[playerTwo].beats === playerOne) {
        alert('Player Two Wins!');
    } else {
        alert('Tie!');
    }
};

fight(playerOne, playerTwo);
```

By objectifying the rock/paper/scissors combinations, the code is IMO significantly easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments and answer are great, so I won't repeat what they said. But you asked for advice, and mine is to not use so many `if` statements to begin with. A big part of programming is learning how to cut down on unnecessary or repeated code. Data structures like objects and arrays are good for this:

```
var win_conditions = {    //simple object showing which hands beat which
    'rock': 'scissors',
    'paper': 'rock',
    'scissors': 'paper'
}

var fight = function(p1, p2) {
    var result;

    if (!win_conditions.hasOwnProperty(p1) || !win_conditions.hasOwnProperty(p2)) {
        result = false;       //error! user typed something invalid
    } else {
        if (win_conditions[p1] == p2) {
            result = 'Player One wins!';
        } else if (win_conditions[p2] == p1) {
            result = 'Player Two wins!';
        } else {
            result = 'Tie!';
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var fight_result = false;
var prompt_text = 'Choose rock, paper, or scissors';
var playerOne = prompt(prompt_text); 
var playerTwo = prompt(prompt_text); 

//keep asking until the user types a valid option
while (!fight_result) {
    fight_result = fight(playerOne.toLowerCase(), playerTwo.toLowerCase());
}
alert(fight_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug your JavaScript Code. When you debug your code change the `alert()` to `console.log()` and probably `playerOne/playerTwo` to simple strings.

(Doesn't fit your question perfectly, but if you continue learning it's a good advice overall.)